AWS Sagemaker Model Monitoring: Merge Predicted vs Actual
I want to deploy a model on AWS Sagemaker Endpoint. Going through the documentation, I am clear about everything except this one thing:
Sagemaker Model monitoring is supposed to monitor the model quality by comparing the predicted outputs vs the actual data. Sagemaker records the model input data and the predictions in a repository like S3. This data is later merged with the actual data to derive the model accuracy and other parameters.
The model will be called at real time for a range of inputs. We only send the parameters to the model in payload which are actually used by the model. Hence we do not send any identifier information like order id, date, time etc. to the model endpoint.
Then how does Sagemaker combine the predicted vs actual data? Is there a mechanism to provide this information which is hidden in the documentation somewhere?
